# Problems with using oneOf in @Schema annotation with springdoc

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

I have the next code in my Spring Boot app:

```
@Schema(description = "Example field",
        anyOf = {
            ExampleResponse.class,
            AnotherExampleResponse.class
        }
)
private Object field;
```

and I expect that there should be two optional types in swagger-ui. But there is no types at all.
What am I doing wrong?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer. I used oneOf property uncorrectly: i had to use it in a definition of API and inside of @ApiResponce annotation like this:

```
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "403",
description = "Example",
content = @Content(schema = @Schema( oneOf = 
{ 
 ExampleResponse.class, 
 ErrorResponse.class
}
)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an interface that you will implement in the various classes

```java
@Schema(
  oneOf = {
    ExampleResponse.class,
    AnotherExampleResponse.class
  }
)
public interface OneOfExampleResponseAnotherExampleResponse {}
```

Below are the various reference models

```java
public class ExampleResponse implements OneOfExampleResponseAnotherExampleResponse {

}
```

```java
public class AnotherExampleResponse implements OneOfExampleResponseAnotherExampleResponse {

}
```

Now it will be enough to declare a field of type OneOfExampleResponseAnotherExampleResponse

```java
private OneOfExampleResponseAnotherExampleResponse field;
```